# Dynamically Create box() within tabItem()

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm building a `shiny` app with `shinydashboard`. Its purpose is to display a set of 'cards' (technically `box()` elements) within each `tabItem()` (i.e. each page of the dashboard). The app is driven by an external .csv file (in this reprex the object `dat`) which (1) defines the pages within the app and (2) specifies the number of `box()` elements within each page.

I have been able to successfully create a set of `tabItem`'s (i.e. pages) using category in `dat`. From here, I can't figure out how to dynamically add the correct number of boxes to each `tabItem`. If you inspect `dat` you will see that there are two categories (pages): blue and green. The blue category requires me to render two boxes (Box A and Box B) whereas the green category requires me to render boxes C - E. Thus, the page called 'Blue' should render two boxes, while the page called 'Green' should render three boxes.

Could someone help me with the below code so that the correct boxes are rendered for the correct pages? Extra gratitude if the box_name and box_desc can appear as the `box()` title and contents, respectively!

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dat<-tibble::tibble(category = c("blue", "blue", "green", "green", "green"), 
                    box_name = c("Box A", "Box B", "Box C", "Box D", "Box E"),
                    box_desc = c("Foo", "Bar", "Bar", "Foo", "Foo"))

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Blue", tabName = "blue", icon = icon("dashboard")),
    menuItem("Green", icon = icon("th"), tabName = "green")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  uiOutput("render_reports")
)
header<-dashboardHeader()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$render_reports <- renderUI({
    
    pages <- lapply(unique(dat$category), function(name){
      
      tabItem(tabName = name, fluidRow(box(
        title = name, paste0("Something here about ", name), width = 12, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary"
      )),

      fluidRow(
        
        box(title = "box_title here", "box_desc here")
        
      ))
    })
    
    items <- c(pages)
    do.call(tabItems, items)
    
  })
  
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is `renderUI` required?

It works fine (and is faster) without `renderUI`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dat <- tibble::tibble(
  category = c("blue", "blue", "green", "green", "green"),
  box_name = c("Box A", "Box B", "Box C", "Box D", "Box E"),
  box_desc = c("Foo", "Bar", "Bar", "Foo", "Foo")
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Blue", tabName = "blue", icon = icon("dashboard")),
  menuItem("Green", tabName = "green", icon = icon("th"))
))

body <- dashboardBody({
  items <- lapply(unique(dat$category), function(name) {
    tabItem(tabName = name, fluidRow(
      lapply(which(dat$category %in% name), function(i) {
        box(
          dat$box_desc[i],
          title = dat$box_name[i],
          paste0("Something here about ", name),
          width = 12,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          status = "primary"
        )
      }))
    )})
  do.call(tabItems, items)
})

header <- dashboardHeader()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

With `renderUI` the items are rendered only after switching the tabs - because the boxes are not existing when the dashboardBody is first rendered:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

dat <- tibble::tibble(
  category = c("blue", "blue", "green", "green", "green"),
  box_name = c("Box A", "Box B", "Box C", "Box D", "Box E"),
  box_desc = c("Foo", "Bar", "Bar", "Foo", "Foo")
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
  menuItem("Blue", tabName = "blue", icon = icon("dashboard")),
  menuItem("Green", tabName = "green", icon = icon("th"))
))

body <- dashboardBody(uiOutput("renderReports"))
header <- dashboardHeader()

ui <- dashboardPage(header, sidebar, body)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$renderReports <- renderUI({
    items <- lapply(unique(dat$category), function(name) {
      tabItem(tabName = name, fluidRow(
        lapply(which(dat$category %in% name), function(i) {
        box(
          dat$box_desc[i],
          title = dat$box_name[i],
          paste0("Something here about ", name),
          width = 12,
          solidHeader = TRUE,
          status = "primary"
        )
      }))
    )})
    do.call(tabItems, items)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers; both UI only and server. At the moment, the app could run without any server-side code. I built my version mostly in server in case in the future I'd needed to do some server-side processing.