# Supply the function dashboardbody with a list of functions

Tags: r, list, function, shiny

I have a list of ui functions one for each R-Tool we have. Something like:

```
myTool1ui <- function ()
{
   tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 12,
              h2("R-Tool",align="center")
            )
          )
          ,
          box(
            h3("test."), width = 12,
          ),
          box(
            h3("Test"), width = 12,
}
```

etc. These are at the moment called in the dashboardbody:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( title = "Tools"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarID", menuItem("Startseite",tabName = "tab1",icon = icon("fas fa-home",verify_fa = FALSE)))),
  skin = "blue",
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems
    (
      myTool1ui(),
      myTool2ui()
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I would like to automate that each time one adds a tool as a new skript with a ui, it is automatically loaded in the dashboardBody without manually adding it here to the list.
I have managed to autatically create a list of functions of all the tools located at the directory.

```
tools <- list.dirs(path = file.path(Workdirectory,"Tools"), full.names = FALSE, recursive = FALSE)
for ( tool in tools )
{
  toolShinyDir <- file.path(Workdirectory, "Tools", tool, paste0(tool,"_shiny.R"))
  source(toolShinyDir)
  toolUIList <- c(toolUI, get(paste0(tool,"ui")) )
}
```

But I struggle giving that list of ui functions in tabItems and ultimatly to the dashboardbody.

In the post [Unpacking argument lists for ellipsis in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3414078/unpacking-argument-lists-for-ellipsis-in-r) I found this approach using injection:

```
rlang::inject(tabItems(!!!toolUI))
```

But this gives me:

```
function()
{
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          h2("Dashboard tab content")
  )
}
<bytecode: 0x0000019d0d38d488>
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.
```

or `do.call` which gives me essantially the same error. I feel like the problem is that there is a difference between `myToolui` and `myToolui()`. If I create the vector as `toolUI <- c(myTool1,myTool2)` I get as an output:

```
toolUI
[[1]]
function()
{
  tabItem(tabName = "dashboard",
          h2("Dashboard tab content")
  )
}
<bytecode: 0x0000019d0d38d488>

[[2]]
function()
{
  tabItem(tabName = "widgets",
          h2("Widgets tab content")
  )
}
```

Whereas when I write `toolUI <- c(myTool1(),myTool2())` which is probably more what I need I get

```
> toolUI
$name
[1] "div"

$attribs
$attribs$role
[1] "tabpanel"

$attribs$class
[1] "tab-pane"

$attribs$id
[1] "shiny-tab-dashboard"


$children
$children[[1]]
<h2>Dashboard tab content</h2>


$name
[1] "div"

$attribs
$attribs$role
[1] "tabpanel"

$attribs$class
[1] "tab-pane"

$attribs$id
[1] "shiny-tab-widgets"


$children
$children[[1]]
<h2>Widgets tab content</h2>
```

Which is not the same as `myToolui()`. I have also tried lapply which doesn't work either

```
lapply(toolUI,tabItems)
[1] "div"
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.
```

**Edit: I tried out with `source`** Here ist my tabItem that is saved in a script called myTool1ui.R

```
tabItem(tabName = "tab1",
          fluidRow(
            column(
              width = 12,
              h2("R-Tool",align="center")
            )
          )
          ,
          box(
            h3("test."), width = 12,
          ),
          box(
            h3("Test"), width = 12,
          )
  )
```

When I try to call it via `source` in the dashboadBody:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

tooluiDirectoryList <- c("directory_of_myTool1ui.R")

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader( title = "Tools"),
  dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarID", menuItem("Startseite",tabName = "tab1"))),
  skin = "blue",
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems
    (
       lapply(tooluiDirectoryList, source, local = TRUE)
    )
  )
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I get the error `Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'.`

**Edit:** I found a not so esthetic solution

```
help <- function(x)
{
  x$value
}
do.call(tabItems,lapply(lapply(list, source, local = TRUE),help))
```

Comment: How do you call the corresponding `menuItem`s?

Comment: Is this just about separating the `tabItem`s into different files? If so, there is no need to wrap them in a function. You could call them via `source(local = TRUE)`. To make your current approach work I guess you'll need to combine `do.call` and `lapply` as done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70034827/dynamically-create-box-within-tabitem/70035465#70035465). For detailed answers please provide us with a [reproducible example](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-workflow.html#getting-help).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is indeed only about splitting the tabItems in different scripts. I tried the appoach with `source` as it seems to be the solution with fewest effort as I have already a lot of code. I answered you in my edited post.

Comment: I found a solution. See Edit in my Post.